# Manipulate string in assembly x86 (mov and print to screen)

Tags: string, assembly, tasm

I'm working on a larger project but I'm stuck with string manipulation. My assembly file includes math coprocessor operations (it starts the coprocessor with "FINIT") but I don't think it should be interfering at all.
Basically, I have some strings that are 50 bytes long each:

```
$s db 50 dup (?), '$'
_cte_14 db "hello world", '$', 39 dup (?)
```

I need to assign the value stored in variable "_cte_14" to variable "$s"
I attempted to use a register to temporarily store the value, like this:

```
mov cx, _cte_14
mov $s, cx
```

but I get the "operand types do not match" error.

Since I know the AX, BX, CX, DX registers only hold 16 bits, I thought maybe I need to work with the memory address of the first string character, so I tried:

```
mov bx, offset _cte_14
mov $s, bx
```

but the same error shows up.

I'm using TASM to compile for an x86 processor. What would be the right way to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You need to copy the characters in a loop, or using string move (`movsb`) instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for to copy the characters in a loop:

```
s db 51 dup ('$')
_cte_14 db "hello world"
len = ($ - _cte_14)    ; (current location - offset _cte_14)
40 dup ('$')

mov si, offset _cte_14 ; get source offset
mov di, offset s       ; get destination offset
mov cl, len            ; length of the string
P1:
mov al, [si]           ; get byte from DS:SI
mov [di], al           ; store byte to DS:DI
dec cl                 ; decrease counter, set zero flag if zero
jnz P1                 ; jump if zero flag is not set
```

-- Variation with using a string instruction together with a repeat instruction prefix:

```
mov si, offset _cte_14
mov di, offset s
mov cx, len ; length of the string
cld         ; clear direction flag
rep movsb   ; copy from DS:SI to ES:DI, increase SI+DI, decrease CX, repeat CX times
```

Comment: Some comments in your answer telling what you are providing / fixing would be useful

Comment: Thanks!! I'm still a bit confused though... Since you changed a bit my .data declarations, I don't fully understand your code.
I'm not sure how is it that "len" contains the length of the source string. Also, not sure what the `40 dup ('$')` does.
I tried your code without changing my .DATA segment and manually inserting the source length:
`mov cl, 12   ; length of "hello world$" `
And then added this to print the contents of $s:
`mov DX, OFFSET $s
mov AH, 9
int 21h`

But all I got was the initial "h" and a bunch of blank spaces.

Comment: Nevermind! Just found out what was missing: your loop code was perfect, only missing `inc si` and `inc di`. Added that right before `dec cl` and it worked like a charm.
Thanks!!